# Oracle - Select distinct on multiple columns where count = 1

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I was wondering if anyone could help me out.  I am wanting to write a query which identifies the manufacturer and model of cars in which **only 1** was sold on the current day if that particular manufacturer/model combination had not been sold before

lets say I have a table called carsSold which has 4 columns: ID,  manufacturer,  model and dateCreated and has the following data:
[image: Table Data]

What I want to do is only return the manufacturer and model rows where the entry was created on the current day and there is only 1 of that type of combination (from any date in history).  If the currentDate was 08-08-2016 from my data set I would expect to see id’s 1, 2, 4 and 7.

Is it possible to do all this?  It seems like quite a lot to achieve from a select statement.  I assume it would start something similar to below only it would contain a distinct and count for the two rows manufacturer and model or something along those lines?  Im just not sure how to achieve exactly what I need.

```
 select * 
 from carsSold
 where dateCreated > trunc(sysdate)
```

Thanks in advance for taking the time to look at this and any help I may receive.

Comment: This is unclear. Are you running this "as of" some date in the past, such as 08-08-2016, or are you **only** running this "as of" the current day (today)? If you want to run it as of some date in the past, which perhaps you will input at the time the query is to be run, then there should be no reference to "current" or to `sysdate`. I am confused.

Comment: @mathguy My solution doesn't care whether it's running for current date. It's safer just to assume it could be run for any date. But yes, I'm aware of the distinction between "all date" vs "all dates previous to some date".

Comment: @shawnt - that is incorrect. Besides needing to change from `sysdate` to "some" input date in your solution, which is not difficult, you will also need some other changes - the `count()` condition may fail if there are LATER entries in the table. (Not difficult either, for example with a `where` clause - but your solution doesn't work *as is* for the more general question.)

Comment: @mathguy I understand where you're coming from and I've had to explain it to people before. I do try to write queries that will work regardless of data to be added later and to clarify that point. This time it just seemed easier to answer the question as posed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select min(Id), Manufacturer, Model, min(dateCreated)
from carsSold
group by Manufacturer, Model
having count(*) = 1 and min(dateCreated) = trunc(sysdate);
```

This is a pretty standard `group by` query. The `having` guarantees that we only get groups with a single row. The condition against `dateCreated` must use an aggregate but since there's only one row in the group then `min()` is really the same thing.

Paraphrasing: Return all groups where the combination of manufacturer and model is counted once and the earliest date of those is the current day (or any date of your choosing.) The id and created date values are recovered as dummy aggregates.

**EDIT**: It's pretty clear to me that you don't intend to run this query retrospectively and that you'll only be interested in using a date of current day. So I didn't feel the need to make this comment earlier. But if you did need to look back in time then it's quite trivial to add `where dateCreated <= <some date>` and substitute the same date in the `having` clause so that all later-created rows are not considered.

**Edit 2**: To simply get the earliest row for each combination you can use `not exists`. There are actually multiple ways to express this query but here is a simple one. It's really not even related to the query above.

```
select * from carsSold c
where not exists (
    select 1 from carsSold c2
    where
            c2.Manufacturer = c.Manufacturer
        and c2.Model = c.Model
        and c2.dateCreated < c.dateCreated
)
```

Comment: Thanks shawnt00 for that brilliant answer and detailed explanation it is very much appreciated.  I have one more question though.  If I wanted to alter the query slightly so that I only cared if the first manufacturer/model combination was bought on the current day is all I would have to do is remove the having count(*) = 1 from the query?  so Instead it would just be having min(dateCreated) = trunc(sysdate);  Ie, I'm wanting to retrieve all records where the FIRST Model/Manufacturer was purchased on the current day even if there more of the same combination bought later that day.

Comment: So in my data set above if 08-08-2016 was the current date I would also see id 9 or 10 returned (depending on the timestamp and which one was inserted earlier, i will use >trunc(sysdate) as opposed to =trunc(sysdate) as we are now talking about timestamps) as although there are two the first one was purchased on the current date.

Comment: @user3781095 Basically yes to all of that. The only potential snag at that point is the assumption that `min(Id)` corresponds to the row as the earliest timestamp. See edit above.

Comment: Excellent,  Thanks once again for your input :)